# How can I make the NVIDIA hdmi sound work?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound

I'm new in the Ubuntu scene and I cant make the sound come out through the HDMI port. I was able to install the NVIDIAa driver properly for my Gefoerce 220 graphics card, I set up ALSA and made the NVIDIDA card the default. Still I got no option on settings to set the audio output to HDMI. Please help me, I do not want to go back to Windows

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run `alsamixer` hit `F6` and select your GPU's audio chip then un-mute everything on it
Sometimes it is necessary to reset audio config, delete your ~/.pulse or ~/.config/pulse folder logout then login and reconfigure the HDMI audio in the audio settings
be sure to try all the hdmi options, i have 4 but only one works on my gtx 550 ti